# Unable to compile Linux dtb

Tags: linux, device-tree

I am trying to compile the dts file for beaglebone black. I have cloned the git repository from this location git://git.ti.com/ti-linux-kernel/ti-linux-kernel.git and I get the following errors:

1. for beaglebone black:

   ```
   $ dtc -I dts -O dtb -o am335x-boneblack.dtb am335x-boneblack.dts
   ```

   > Error: am335x-boneblack.dts:10.1-9 syntax error
   >   FATAL ERROR: Unable to parse input tree
2. I tried for atmel sam9g20 ek- I get the same error:

   ```
   $ dtc -I dts -O dtb -o at91sam9g20ek_2mmc.dtb at91sam9g20ek_2mmc.dts
   ```

   > Error: at91sam9g20ek_2mmc.dts:9.1-9 syntax error
   >   FATAL ERROR: Unable to parse input tree

But when I use the mainline kernel they compile.

I tried `make ARCH=arm dtbs` also is an error

Could anybody please point me the mistake I am making?

Comment: I have put a fix to this problem using the command 

    make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- am335x-boneblack.dtb

I think the cross compiler is used in some part of dtc compilation. Could anybody explain why this worked?

Comment: You probably need **cpp**, the C preprocessor.

Comment: I believe I have cpp and C preprocessor for I have been developing a lot of projects with QT in C++ for beaglebone and Atmel sam9g20. If I am wrong how do I check this?

Comment: Try shell commands `which cpp` or `cpp -dumpmachine`

Comment: `which cpp` =>
`/usr/bin/cpp` and 
`cpp -dumpmachine` =>
`i686-linux-gnu`

I have posted the output of the commands.

Comment: Yes even I have faced this error.Can someone tell me if I am building/compiling the dtb for a given driver's dts what steps I have to follow(like pacing the dts in what folder, etc...)

Comment: @Raulp Could you please give the hw details and the process you are following to compile

Comment: Its the beagleboneblack(arm) .and the hardware is a led connected via gpios.you can follow this link for what I have done -> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/beagleboard/support/newbies/beaglebone-black/cLDC6Le0Z4A

Comment: @PrajoshPremdas: The dts file (or the board file) includes the dtsi file (SOC descriptor file) and also expects a basic device tree structure inclusion (/dts-v1/) which is required for building. Now again the dtsi file ( for the SOC such as one based on ARM arch) contains various properties which will be only relevant to ARM SOC's . So the same is the requirement for setting up the environment before building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the command `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- dtbs` this problem has been fixed

CROSS_COMPILE can have the compiler of your choice.